# Retrieve a list that is distinct except one datamember

Tags: c#, linq

You have a big list and the goal is to retrieve this new list below

Today:

```
number   color   brand   size   tiresize
-----------------------------------------
1         blue   d       5      6
2         blue   d       5      6
3         red    b       3      3
4         red    b       3      3
etc....
```

Goal:

```
number   color   brand   size   tiresize
-----------------------------------------
          blue   d       5      6
          red    b       3      3
```

The goal is to retrieve a list that is distincted and you remove the "number".

THis sample is a smal one and in reality the list has about 26 datamember.

I was thinking about distinct() but it takes account to all datamember and I dont want to take account to the column "number"

WHen you retrieve the new list, the request is to use the same class before with the distincted list.

```
public Car
{
    public int number
    public string color
    public string brand
    public string size
    public string tiresize
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: GroupBy the fields you'd like to retrieve,,

Comment: Either GroupBy as @AndreaConte suggested or have a look at MoreLinq (on nuget) DistinctBy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var cars = new List<Car>
{
   new Car{number = 1, color="blue", brand="d", size = "5", tiresize = "6"},
   new Car{number = 2, color="blue", brand="d", size = "5", tiresize = "6"},
   new Car{number = 3, color="red", brand="b", size = "3", tiresize = "3"},
   new Car{number = 4, color="red", brand="b", size = "3", tiresize = "3"},
};

var distinctCars = cars.GroupBy(x => new {x.color, x.brand, x.size, x.tiresize});                

foreach (var car in distinctCars)
{
   Console.WriteLine(car.Key.color +  ": " + car.Key.brand +  ": " + car.Key.size +  ": " + car.Key.tiresize);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way, using an anonymous type which has a built-in `Equals` + `GetHashCode` implementation which compares all properties:

```
var distinctCars = cars
    .Select(c => new {c.color, c.brand, c.size, c.tiresize})
    .Distinct()
    .Select(x => new Car {color = x.color, brand = x.brand, size = x.size, tiresize = x.tiresize})
    .ToList(();
```

Other ways would be to

1. override `Equals` + `GetHashCode` in `Car` yourself

   - optionally also implement `IEquatable<Car>`
2. provide a custom `IEqualityComparer<Car>` which you can use in `Distinct`